# Javascript : To text string contains only alpha numaric,$ and _

Tags: javascript

give an example To text string contains only alpha numaric,$ and _  using javascript

Comment: `"a1$_"`? Please try to formulate a proper question. Right now it's impossible to understand what your problem is. Also post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you looking for a regular expression?

Comment: just give me an example how to validate the string that contains alphanumaric and $,_ charatcters. Other than these characters that is invalid string

Comment: @user578542 That's not the nicest way to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var regex = /[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+/ig

For more information see here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: var regExp = /[^a-z0-9$_]/i;
        if( str.match(regExp) != null ) {
                 // invalid string
        }